# Paypal Sandbox: DoExpressCheckoutPayment 10001 Internal Error

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I'm currently working on an e-commerce website, I have integrated Paypal (Express Checkout) and it worked well until yesterday.

When I send the DoExpressCheckoutPayment Request, I receive this response :

```
  "ACK" => "Failure"
  "VERSION" => "204.0"
  "BUILD" => "000000"
  "L_ERRORCODE0" => "10001"
  "L_SHORTMESSAGE0" => "Internal Error"
  "L_LONGMESSAGE0" => "Internal Error"
  "L_SEVERITYCODE0" => "Error"
```

The parameters that I send :

```
'USER' => $username,
'PWD' => $password,
'SIGNATURE' => $signature,
'VERSION' => "204.0",
'METHOD' => 'DoExpressCheckoutPayment',
'TOKEN' => $token,
'PAYERID' => $payerid,
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => $price,
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT' => $price,
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'EUR'
```

Do you have Any idea ?

Comment: I am facing with a similar issue here in the US, but it is happening on my Staging account and not Production account. It started on Friday the 5th for us.

My transaction is in USD and I am using version 106. I tried moving up to version 204 but still got the error 10001 (Internal Error).

Our Staging site does not use SSL while production does. I wonder if PayPal changed something on their end that does not serve non-SSL sites.

Comment: While the API method 'DoExpressCheckoutPayment' is failing, payments are being received under the merchant account. So seems like something is getting messed up in the last step where transaction details need to be reported back via the API response.

Answer (score -1):

I could solve that by creating a new buyer and merchant account at https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts both in the **same country** (and so using the **same currency**).

I updated the API credentials (username, password, signature) from the new merchant and payed with the new buyer account.